# How do you view terraform input variables and object values during validate/plan/apply, for debugging?

Tags: terraform

One would think, or at least hope, that setting TF_log=TRACE would allow you to see the values, maybe even value types, of variables being passed into modules., but it does not.

What are the best practices for debugging data flows inside of a terraform validate, plan, and apply operations?